# Word 2007 add-in for a custom ribbon - ribbon not visible in the saved document

Tags: vsto, ms-office, openxml-sdk, ribbon-control

I have a requirement where I need to have a custom ribbon added to the Word 2007 file which will be populated from some items. I created a add-in using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) and pressing F5 opens Word file contains the newly added custom ribbon. But I save that word file and open that again and It does not have that newly added custom ribbon. I am sure I am missing something here.Could anybody throw some light?

Answer (score 0):

> I save that word file and open that again

Are you opening it again outside of the Word instance running from Visual Studio? Your add-in might only be available when you're debugging the project.

Check if an entry for your add-in exists in the registry, under:

`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\`.

If no entry exists, I've found that the easiest way to deploy a VSTO add-in to your machine is to create a setup project for it in Visual Studio.

Comment: No add-in. I am using Open Xml SDK.