# Word add-in only available in debug

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in, ribbon, msdeploy

So I have a Word add-in that adds a custom Ribbon and a couple of other right-click menu's. This all works fine while I'm developing (release or debug mode) however, if I publish the add-in and deploy it, i.e. install the program then the Ribbon just shows a blank tab and none of the buttons work, but all the other features of the add-in will work fine such as the right click menu's. The same occurs if I have recently ran the program through VS (therefore installing it) then trying to open Word.

So it seems as though the program will only be fully functional whilst I am debugging it in VS. I saw a post that said to check if my registry included an entry for my add-in, and it does not [1]. The registry location is:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\.
```

[1] [Word 2007 add-in for a custom ribbon - ribbon not visible in the saved document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497749/word-2007-add-in-for-a-custom-ribbon-ribbon-not-visible-in-the-saved-document)

Comment: there could be some error when loading adding, is there anything in error log or try VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS

Comment: I've added the VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS = 0 to the environment variables but nothing comes up, so it seems to load fine. Where can I find said error log? Thanks.